# Running Docker containers on Azure using docker-py

Tags: python, azure, docker

I can find all of the ingredients for what I want to do, but I'm not sure if I can put them together.

Ultimately, I want a Python process to be able to create and manage Docker instances running on Azure.

This link shows that you can use the Docker API to fire up instances on Azure: https://docs.docker.com/engine/context/aci-integration/.  It's Beta, but I've been able to run my own container on Azure after logging in, using something like this:

```
docker --context myacicontext run hello-world
```

The second half of my problem is to call this from docker-py.  The vanilla usage of docker-py is nice and striaght-forward, but I can't find any reference to the flag "--context" in the docker-py docs (https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/).

Is there a way for configuring docker-py such that it provides a --context?

---

EDIT:

Thanks to @CharlesXu pointing me in the right direction, I have now found that the following docker-py command **does** have an effect:

```
docker.context.ContextAPI.set_current_context("myacicontext")
```

This changes the default context used by the docker cmd line interface, so

```
C:\Users\MikeSadler>docker ps -a
```

will subsequently list the containers running in Azure, and not locally.

*However*, the docker.from_env().containers.list(all=all) command stubbornly continues to return the local containers.  This is true even if you restart the Python session and create a new client from a completely fresh start.

---

CONCLUSION:

Having spoken with the Docker developers, as of October 2020 docker-py officially does not support Cloud connections.  They are currently using GRPC protocols to manage Cloud runs, and this *may* be incorporated into docker-py in the future.

Comment: It seems like the context is set while building the image: https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/1.6.0/api/

Comment: @CasperDijkstra I *believe* that is where the Docker daemon that you are speaking with is, rather than what is given to that daemon as the --context.  I am already running this Python within a container, and the Python is using the host container's daemon to run docker.  I need to provide *that* daemon with this context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid there is no way to do things like the command `docker --context myacicontext run hello-world` does. And there is also no parameter like `--context` in the SDK. As I know, you can set the current context use the SDK like this:

```
import docker
docker.context.config.write_context_name_to_docker_config('context_name')
```

But when you use the code:

```
client = docker.from_env()
client.containers.run('xxx')
```

Then it will set the context into `default`. It means you cannot run the containers into ACI. I think it may be a bug that needs to be fixed. I'm not very very sure, but that's it right now.

Comment: Thanks - I hadn't found the write_context_name_to_docker_config function yet.  Have you reported it as a bug?  The fact that they have a context at all suggests that they *intend* to support it...

Comment: @MikeSadler I didn't report it as a bug because I'm not very sure. You still don't find the function?

Comment: Thanks, Charles.  There's definitely something there.  docker.context.ContextAPI.get_context("azure_context") returns an object which knows it is an "aci" context, so it looks like there is some real functionality there.  I will experiment...

Comment: docker.context.ContextAPI.set_current_context("hhhoih") also returns an error (i.e. if the context does not exist).  However, docker.from_env() is still ignoring it...

Comment: @MikeSadler Yes, that's what I have found. So that I think it may be a bug.

Comment: @MikeSadler Well, if it's helpful please accept it. And I think you can report as an issue.

Comment: I've found an E-mail for one of the maintainers.  All of the context-support code seems to be operating correctly, so I think we may just be missing a trick.  I'll see what they come back with - with any luck we might get a solution to both of our problems!

Comment: Strangely, docker.context.ContextAPI.set_current_context("myacicontext") **does** set the context used by the docker api (as run on an independent cmd line).  However, the docker-py functionality stubbornly uses the default context.

Comment: @MikeSadler That's the issue I found and told you in the answer. So I think it may be a bug.

Comment: Thanks, Charles.  I actually spoke with the Docker developers, and they said that this hasn't been implemented for Azure.  They've given my a set of GRPC protocol definitions, and I'm having *some* luck, but it is not as rich an interface.  They might be extending docker-py at some point in the future.

Comment: @MikeSadler It sounds great if it would be fixed.